# Hive UDF for SOAP XPath?

Tags: soap, xpath, hadoop, namespaces, hive

In the Hive language there are XPath functions but they do not support XML namespaces.

I am in need of a `UDF` for SOAP message XPath processing with Hive.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest building custom UDF which will support parsing of SOAP messages.

There is good guide here how to build UDFs http://snowplowanalytics.com/blog/2013/02/08/writing-hive-udfs-and-serdes/

You can use any parses to parse SOAP message and integrate it into UDF.

Thanks,
Dino